# Video transcoder encoder decoder unable to return original buffer

Tags: java, android, video-processing, android-mediacodec, video-conversion

I am working on a Video encoding and decoding app.
I am using **[grishka/android-video-transcoder](https://github.com/grishka/android-video-transcoder)** library to get the buffers.

What the library doing is to convert the video frames into the `COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar` format. Which is working fine. But when it encodes the video again to its original frames. It will not return the origin video.

This is the screenshot of my video out after decoding and encoding.

[image: Video Screenshot]

I have done so much R&D on the same to get the origin video. But not getting any success. Please help me out if anyone facing the same issue or resolved this issue.

The whole code is the same as per the above-given GitHub sample link.

Comment: Did you checked the outputs formats for encoder/decoders? Are you sure that the input dimensions are the same as the codec output format dims?Did you tried with many videos with different dims?

Comment: _`"I have done so much R&D on the same to get the origin video. But not getting any success"`_ well we can't guess what this means.. What is the main thing you've tried? **(1)** What happens when you set output encoder as `COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible`?... **(2)** What is your advantage or purpose of using this Qualcomm format? I ask because obviously it messes up your pixels, why even touch it if you don't have a reversing algorithm?